# Is the following topology pseudometrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \{a, b\}$. Define a topology on X by
$$\tau = \{X, \emptyset, \{a\}\}.$$
Is $\tau$ pseudometrizable? Why?

So I definded a disk around $\{a\}$ such that the disk is a subset of $\{a\}$. And I want to get the reverse inclusion, $\{a\} \subseteq$ of the disk around $a.$ So that I can get the result that the disk is equal to $\{a\}$.

I just need help with the reverse inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

A pseudometric on a $T_0$ space is a metric, and $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is $T_0$, so if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ were pseudometrizable, it would be metrizable and therefore Hausdorff. But it’s not Hausdorff, so it can’t be pseudometrizable.

Answer (score 2):

For the space to be pseudometrizable, it is necessary that there exists a *pseudometric* $d : X \times X \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ such that the topology that this pseudometric induces (defined similar to that of usual metric spaces) coincides with $\tau$.

Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is pseudometrizable with pseudometric $d$. Since $\{a\}$ is in $\tau$, there needs to be an element $x \in X$ and a radius $r>0$ such that $a \in B(x,r) \subset \{a\}$, where $B(x,r) = \{y \in X : d(x,y) < r \}$. But observe that this condition is in fact the following equality: $B(x,r) = \{a\}$.

As $X$ consists of only two elements, let's explore the possibilities:

- If $x=a$, then we need $d(a,b) > 0$, otherwise $B(a,r) = X$ for every radius. However, in this case, check that $B(b,\frac{d(a,b)}{2}) = \{b\}$, which is not in $\tau$.
- If $x = b$, then $\{b\} \subset B(b,r)$ for all $r>0$, so the desired equality cannot hold.

Hence the space is not pseudometrizable.